# Re-submit MySQL Calls, then refresh data when app is refreshed

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I have written an app that calls a stored procedure to update a table in MySQL, then queries the new table (both using RMySQL), does some data manipulation and plots a bunch of graphs.

I designed the app to include a refresh button, with the assumption that when the page is refreshed shiny would re-query the database and re-calculate all the values for the outputs. After testing this, however, it is not doing so (and keeps the old values from pre- refresh). I've tried closing the connection to the database when the refresh button is pressed, then re-opening it, but this just causes the app to disconnect.

My question is why does it remember the old values rather than update them, and is there some way i can tell it to re-do all of it after a refresh? Apologies if this is a really basic question, anything that could point me in the right direction would be great.

I've included an example of the relevant chunks below, although not sure how useful that will be!

```
 library(RMySQL)
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyjs)

 con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="abfd", 
 username="abc",password="abc123", host='blah, port=3306))

 con2 = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="abfd", 
 username="abc",password="abc123", host='blah, port=3306))

 frfr<-dbGetQuery(con2, 'CALL Updatedata();' )

 Data<-as.data.frame(dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT Date, Age,Name FROM Results 
 WHERE Date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY Date Asc;'))

 jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"

 ui <- fluidPage(
 shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),

actionButton('Refresh','Refresh Data')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
observeEvent(input$Refresh,{
{js$reset()}
})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: First, your `Data` is declared outside the shiny app. It should be in `server`. Second, in `server`, you observe an event based on `input$Refresh`, but don't update `Data`. You need to make `Data` reactive to this `observeEvent`. Look at `reactive()`...

Comment: Thanks, i'll have another go with it today!